# Performance improvements for query (maybe faulty query)

Tags: mysql

I hope you can help me.

I have three tables:

- Table 1 with 6155 data sets (user information)
- Table 2 with 15 933 data sets (answers of a questionnaire)
- Table 3 with 595 120 data sets (pages visit by user)

I want to join all three tables into one to see which user visited which page and what answers did he submit on the questionnaire
with the following query:

```
SELECT user.email, user.expdata, tp.tstamp as tp_tstamp, mq.tstamp AS mq_tstamp, mq.question1, mq.question2, mq.question3, mq.question4, mq.question5, mq.question6, mq.question7, mq.question8, mq.question9
FROM table1 AS user
INNER JOIN table2 AS mq ON user.id = mq.userid
INNER JOIN table3 AS tp ON user.id = tp.userid
WHERE user.email = "test@test.de"
```

When I submit this query, the browser loads and loads until no results will be shown. I tried to submit these queries one by one:

```
SELECT user.id, user.email, user.expdata
FROM table1 AS user
WHERE user.email = "test@test.de"
```

==> results in 1 data set

```
SELECT tp.tstamp AS tp_tstamp
FROM table3 AS tp 
WHERE tp.userid = "1"
```

==> results in 172 data set

```
SELECT mq.tstamp AS mq_tstamp
FROM table2 AS mq
WHERE mq.userid = "1"
```

==> results in 4 data set

I don't have much experience with sql so I don't know if my query is exactly what I want. I hope you can advice me to a nice solution.

Just ask, if you need some more information, thanks!

Edit: ids & tables where not the same...

DDL:
Table1

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                        `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
                        KEY `email` (`email`) 
                      ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6862 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table2

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                        `tstamp`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question4` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question5` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question6` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question7` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question8` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `question9` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
                      ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16370 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table3

```
CREATE TABLE `table3` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                        `tstamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
                        `pageid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
                      ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=618813 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL Version: 5.6..

Comment: Provide tables DDLs (as CREATE TABLE).

Comment: Does the page visited and the answer are not relative except the user?

Comment: @Akina Inserted the DDLs and yes, only the userid combines all three tables.

Comment: 1) Please give DDLs as text/code, not as screenshots. 2) Remove all excess fields, i.e. which are not used in your query, any table index or some constraint. 3) Additionally - specify MySQL version.

Comment: What is the reason to combine the data from two absolutely unrelative data arrays in one row?

Comment: Hope it's okay now. These data was requested by someone so I thought I could give it to them in one table.

Comment: *I thought I could give it to them in one table* Look. Some user has visited 2 pages and has answered 2 questions. Your query will return 4 records - page1 combined with answer1, page1 and answer2, page2 and answer1, page2 and answer2. Do you want this REALLY? In your case - 4 questions and 172 pages - you'll obtain 172*4=688 rows.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. Since the records will be extraordinary large this is why the query takes so long and no results are shown? Then two queries should be then possible for this, e.g. one query to get the user and his answers and one query to get all the visited pages or?

Comment: Two separate queries is more logical of course. But if you want to combine nevertheless, you must enumerate records in each separate table (after filtering by the user, of course) and then join by this number... but this enumeration is not easy performed in your version, and additionally you'll need to emulate FULL JOIN which is not supported by MySQL.

Comment: Ok sounds complicated to me, but thanks for the clarification!